# Is there some way to use already created database table in voyager?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, voyager

I am using voyager to create admin panel for my app. Link for voyager is  https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager. I need to use already created database tables which I created in phpmyadmin but can not find way to do so. Voyager gives some already built tables like categories, menus, pages etc. and also let us create new tables but how can I use my own created tables which I created in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible use your owns tables, inside bread section should appear the option to make bread of it.

To make a bread of a table you should create the model of that table, if you have the table "articles" you can create the model with "php artisan make:model article"